# How to install realm library into a npm package

Tags: react-native, realm, npm-package

I have created a simple library for react-native using bob

```
npx @react-native-community/bob create react-native-awesome-module
```

with `Native module in Kotlin and Swift` option and followed by `yarn bootstrap`

After this, the example app build successfully using
`yarn example android`

But the problem is when I install realm library (in dependencies in package.json) in the root npm package and import the library it gives the undefined value.
The error is(For android device strange error):

```
Error: Missing Realm constructor. Did you run "pod install"?
```

Is there any way to install the realm in a react-native library?

Comment: did u link these packages ?

Comment: yes, but isn't autolinking should do that?

Comment: some packages don't autolink, it's totally random so it seems like you should link realm manually.